# Get Substring before and after "." full stop, if Not found then get NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I wanted to get the substring after and before the ".", For Example

**Furniture.Chair**  I need furniture in "Category1" column and Chair in "Category2" column but also if the string comes like this :

**Furniture.** then i need "Null" in "Category2" column. but i unable to do this.
please see the below screen for calarification :
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Try parsename function

Comment: I read the details. now i give me an error, posted after 90 minutes :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with data (val) as
(
  select 'furniture' from dual union all -- without the dot 
  select 'furniture.' from dual union all -- dot at the end
  select '.furniture' from dual union all -- dot at the beginning
  select null from dual union all -- no input
  select 'home owners.home.home' from dual union all -- if more than one dot is found
  select 'health and beauty.skin care' from dual -- words followed by dot followed by words
)
, coll as
(
select 
  val, 
  -- [^\.]+  any character sequence other than dot (+ is for one or more)
  -- (\.|) find a dot or nothing - eg. 'furniture' with a dot 
  -- (([^\.]+)) the outer brackets capture the first group \1; 
  --            the first inner brackets capture the second group
  --            the last argument to the regexp_substr below ie. '2' tells 
  --            method our interest is in the second group within the match 
  --            identified by (([^\.]+)(\.|)) 
  regexp_substr(val, '(([^\.]+)(\.|))', 1, 1, null, '2') as first,  
  regexp_substr(val, '(\.(.*))', 1, 1, null, '2') as the_rest 
from data
)
select 
  val, 
  case when first is null then 'Unknown Category' else first end as first,
  case when first is null then 'Unknown Category' else first end as the_rest
from coll
;
```

Comment: One thing more, I wanted to get "Un-known Category" in "first" column if NULL comes and also 
"Un-known Category" in "the_rest" if NULL comes